# How to create a variable dependent column name?

Tags: kdb, qsqlquery

I am struggling to name a column based on a variable.

I want to create a column with a name including the stock symbol, for example `Open_AAPL`, `Open_MSFT`, `Open_ORCL`.

I have tried the following to make the column name `Open_AAPL`:

```
sym: `AAPL
column_name: `$""sv string (`Open_,sym) //merge the symbols (this becomes `Open_AAPL)
t1: select `column_name: first last_trade by date from t
```

and

```
t1: select column_name: first last_trade by date from t
```

which do not work. How can I do this? The reason for doing this is to create a function where I just need to input the different symbols and the column name changes.

Comment: This doesn't feel like a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [functional select](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/funsql/#select) if you require column names that are dynamically produced:

```
q)trade:([]sym:`AAPL`AAPL;last_trade:100 101)
q)select Open_AAPL:first last_trade from trade
Open_AAPL
---------
100
q)parse"select Open_AAPL:first last_trade from trade"
?
`trade
()
0b
(,`Open_AAPL)!,(*:;`last_trade)
q){?[trade;();0b;enlist[`$"Open_",string x]!enlist(first;`last_trade)]}`AAPL
Open_AAPL
---------
100
```